# Groovy map constructor keys to different variable names

Tags: groovy

I have JSON looking like:

```
{
    "days": [
        {
            "mintemp": "21.8"
        }
    ]
}
```

With Groovy, I parse it like this:

```
class WeatherRow {
    String mintemp
}

def file = new File("data.json")
def slurper = new JsonSlurper().parse(file)
def days = slurper.days
def firstRow = days[0] as WeatherRow
println firstRow.mintemp
```

But actually, I would like to name my instance variable something like `minTemp` (or even something completely random, like `numberOfPonies`). Is there a way in Groovy to map a member of a map passed to a constructor to something else?

To clarify, I was looking for something along the lines of `@XmlElement(name="mintemp")`, but could not easily find it:

```
class WeatherRow {
    @Element(name="mintemp")
    String minTemp
}
```

Comment: No, you'll have to manipulate the map to change the key names, or write something that generates `WeatherRow` classes from maps with arbitrary key names

Comment: @tim_yates I was afraid so. As I'm new to Groovy, is there any other way to unmarshall JSON to POGO's that has this behavior?

Comment: Yeah sometimes writing easy custom methods to convert your custom json doesnt hurt. Check my hint.

Answer (score 1):

Create a constructor that takes a map.

Runnable example:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def testJsonStr = '''
{"days": [
    { "mintemp": "21.8" }
]}'''

class WeatherRow {
    String minTemp
    WeatherRow(map) {
        println "Got called with constructor that takes a map: $map"
        minTemp = map.mintemp
    }
}

def slurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(testJsonStr)
def days = slurper.days
def firstRow = days[0] as WeatherRow
println firstRow.minTemp
```

Result:

```
Got called with constructor that takes a map: [mintemp:21.8]
21.8
```

(of course you'd remove the `println` line, it's just there for the demo)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using annotation and simple custom annotation processor like this:

### 1. Create a Custom Annotation Class

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)  
@interface JsonDeserializer {  
String[] names() default []
}
```

### 2. Annotate your instance fields with the custom annotation

```
class WeatherRow{

@JsonDeserializer(names = ["mintemp"])
String mintemp;

@JsonDeserializer(names = ["mintemp"])
String minTemp;

@JsonDeserializer(names = ["mintemp"])
String numberOfPonies;
```

}

### 3. Add custom json deserializer method using annotation processing:

```
static WeatherRow fromJson(def jsonObject){

    WeatherRow weatherRow = new WeatherRow();
   try{
       weatherRow = new WeatherRow(jsonObject);
      }catch(MissingPropertyException ex){
      //swallow missing property exception.
      }

   WeatherRow.class.getDeclaredFields().each{

       def jsonDeserializer = it.getDeclaredAnnotations()?.find{it.annotationType() == JsonDeserializer}
       def fieldNames = [];

       fieldNames << it.name;

       if(jsonDeserializer){
        fieldNames.addAll(jsonDeserializer.names());

        fieldNames.each{i ->
            if(jsonObject."$i")//TODO: if field type is not String type custom parsing here.
                weatherRow."${it.name}" = jsonObject."$i";
        }

       }

    };

return weatherRow;

}
```

Example:

```
def testJsonStr = '''
{
    "days": [
        {
            "mintemp": "21.8"
        }
    ]
}'''

def parsedWeatherRows = new JsonSlurper().parseText(testJsonStr);

assert WeatherRow.fromJson(parsedWeatherRows.days[0]).mintemp == "21.8"
assert WeatherRow.fromJson(parsedWeatherRows.days[0]).minTemp == "21.8"
assert WeatherRow.fromJson(parsedWeatherRows.days[0]).numberOfPonies == "21.8"
```

Check the full working code at [groovyConsole](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5159582733172736).

Comment: Interesting but I understood the request goes the other way around: `mintemp` in JSON, when parsed, is written to field `minTemp` (or `numberOfPonies`) of `WeatherRow`. Your idea still applies I think, but there is only a need for 1 value in the annotation, and the example would be clearer if reversed (assuming I understood it right). But I also suspect there is a much easier solution in that case, with a simple `WeatherRow.minTemp()` method that would read `mintemp`...

Comment: @HuguesMoreau is right, it should be the other way around. I have JSON that has a `mintemp` name, and I would like that to map to a `minTemp` variable. But this answer is very interesting (and has quite some new information for me), so I'm gonna study it in more detail.

Comment: oh ok, I reveresed it you can check the solution